# How to access a file in Client-Server architecture using Sockets in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I need to read a "bdd.txt" file placed on a Virtual Machine on my computer. I made a client/server system in Java. My Server.java is on my VM (Ubuntu) with a "database" (the bdd.txt file in the same folder), and my Client.java is on my Windows 7.

So far I have split my code into 2 different files (Server/Client) and I made the connexion between my Windows 7 and my VMware Player's Ubuntu. When I start my server on my VM, it listens on a port number x, then I go back on my Windows and run my client. It asks to make the connexion and then, back on my VM, I print a message "The connexion is made" and my app is running. So now I can communicate between them. I have just used socket = new Socket("my VM ip address",portNumber); and it works. But now, I have no idea how to adapt my code to reach my bdd.txt file I moved on my VM.

**How can I now read the bdd.txt file, to have access to the pin codes ?
Why is my `new Client()` never called in my program?**

Here is Client.java :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int pinSize = 0;

          //set up server communication
          Socket clientSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),1234);
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
          PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Enter pin : ");
          String password = scanner.next();
          pinSize = password.length();

          //send PIN to server
          out.println(password);

          if (pinSize != 4) { 
      System.out.println("Pin must be 4 digits");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Checking...");
    }

          out.flush();

          //get response from server
          String response = in.readLine();
          System.out.println(response);

          in.close();
          out.close();
          clientSocket.close();
        }
}
```

Here is Server.java (in the same folder as bdd.txt):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Server {

    private static ServerSocket server;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

          server = new ServerSocket(1234);
          Socket socket = server.accept();      
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
          PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

          //Listen for client requests:
          String request;
          while ((request = in.readLine()) != null) {

            //check PIN, send result
            boolean pinCorrect = checkPin(request);
            out.println(pinCorrect ? "yes" : "no");
            out.flush();
          }

          out.close();
          in.close();
          socket.close();
        }

        /**
         * Check if PIN is in bdd.txt
         * @throws IOException 
         */
        private static boolean checkPin(String pin) throws IOException {
          boolean result = false;
          File file = new File("bdd.txt");
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
          String line;
          while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            result |= (line.equals(pin));
          }
          in.close();
          return result;
        }
}
```

Comment: We don't need screenshots or 100 yards of Swing code to answer a simple question about sockets.

Comment: I thought it would be better to understand what I am trying to do. No need to talk that way, how about giving me some help ?

Comment: Study about the basic document of sockets, that would be helpful to you.

Comment: How about asking a question that doesn't require everybody to wade through yards of irrelevancy? How about making an effort to isolate what it is that you're actually asking? How about improving the probability of getting an answer? This isn't your personal support desk. We are volunteers. I suggest you conduct yourself accordingly. It's in your own interest.

Comment: @Sathesh, I have google "file base web server coded in Java", but nothing helped me that much so far.

Comment: @EJP I see but this is what I am doing precisely, don't you think it takes more time to explain what I want to do and put screenshot instead of just asking to solve my problem with 5 lines of code ? Anyway I have been thinking of doing that before posting.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

Comment: @Jay yes that's exactly what I tried to look in order to adapt my code to it. But I can not figure out how to do with a "file". In those examples, it is always printing text or whatever, I have no idea how to make the same thing with file-reading.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of irrelevant stuff in you question, it's hard to see how your program works.

Here's what should happen:

Client side:

- User inputs a number
- Client sends user's number to server
- Client receives response from server, and displays it

Server side:

- Server listens for client connection
- Server receives number from client
- Server checks number against file `bbd.txt`
- If number exists in file, return `yes` else return `no`

I have written some simple code to show you, excluding UI stuff:

Client.java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  //set up server communication
  Socket clientSocket = new Socket("ip.address",1234);
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());


  //send PIN to server
  out.println("9.8.7.6");
  out.flush;

  //get response from server
  String response = in.readLine();
  System.out.println(response);

  in.close();
  out.close();
  clientSocket.close();
}
```

Server.java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  //Set up client communication
  ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1234);
  Socket socket = server.accept();      
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

  //Listen for client requests:
  String request;
  while ((request = in.readLine()) != null) {

    //check PIN, send result
    boolean pinCorrect = checkPin(request);
    out.println(pinCorrect ? "yes" : "no");
    out.flush();
  }

  out.close();
  in.close();
  socket.close();
}

/**
 * Check if PIN is in bdd.txt
 */
private static boolean checkPin(String pin) {
  boolean result = false;
  File file = new File("bdd.txt");
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
  String line;
  while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    result |= (line.equals(pin));
  }
  in.close();
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you NickJ, but this way I do not use File anymore ? Since my "database" is a file, should I change request to File ?

Comment: I have updated the answer to include code for checkPin(). That's where you read your file. It will return true if the PIN entered by the user in in the file, otherwise false. I have not checked it, and you'll need to add exception handling before it will compile.

Comment: Thanks, just one question, in Client.java BufferedReader and PrintWriter both use socket.getIn/OutputStream. Is this "socket" or "clientSocket" such as the previous declaration ?

Comment: I tried this solution, but I could not manage to make it work.

Comment: Sorry, that should be clientSocket in Client.java

Comment: No problem. I have no idea why it prints "no" in the console, and nothing happens next.

Comment: 'no' is the server response meaning that the PIN is wrong. The client should check the server response and display a message.

Comment: Ok, now I am trying to replace your "out.println("9.8.7.6");" with a pin entered in the app by the user. But my class BoutonListener is no longer working with this  configuration. I can not do the same checkPin verification with the UI app.

Comment: I tried to adapt this code with a scanner to let the enter use a pin instead of forcing to send "out.println("9.8.7.6");". So far I have the code you can see in my first post (I have edited), but I have difficulties to recover my loop from the beginning to make the 3 tries and so.. With this type of architecture I have the feeling everything is different.